# MAKEFILE header file error when try to generate dependency file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Code structure

```
work
├── code
|     | 
|     ├──inc/
|     |   └── main.h 
|     |
|     └── main.c 
├── _Build/
│         └── Makefile
```

Below is the Makefile code

```
WORKSPACE = ..

DIR_CODE = $(WORKSPACE)/code
DIR_BIN  = $(WORKSPACE)/bin
DIR_OBJ  = $(WORKSPACE)/obj

C_SRC_WITH_PATH = $(shell find $(DIR_CODE) -iname *.c)
C_SRC_ONLY_PATH = $(patsubst %/,%,$(sort $(dir $(C_SRC_WITH_PATH))))

TARGET   = $(DIR_BIN)/application

.PHONY : all run clean

all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : ../obj/main.o | $(DIR_BIN) ../deps
        gcc $^ -o $@

../obj/main.o : ../code/main.c ../deps | $(DIR_OBJ)
        gcc -c -o $@ $< -MMD -MP -MF ../deps/main.d

$(DIR_BIN) $(DIR_OBJ) ../deps :
        mkdir -p $@

run :
        $(TARGET)

clean :
        rm -rf $(DIR_BIN) $(DIR_OBJ) ../deps

-include ../deps/main.d
```

I am getting below error

```
gcc -c -o ../obj/main.o ../code/main.c -MMD -MF ../deps/main.d
../code/main.c:2:10: fatal error: main.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "main.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:26: ../obj/main.o] Error 1
```

Although I am trying to generate the dependency file in the `makefile`, the file `main.d` is not generated and getting error for `main.h` file which is included in `main.c` file.

Any guidance is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with `.d` files etc.  The compiler can't find your header file, because you haven't add the correct directory to the compile line.  If your headers live in `../code/inc` then you have to add this to your compile line, else how can the compiler find them?

Since you're not using any make variables to hold the compiler or flags, you'll have to add it directly to your recipe:

```
../obj/main.o : ../code/main.c ../deps | $(DIR_OBJ)
        gcc -I../code/inc -c -o $@ $< -MMD -MP -MF ../deps/main.d
```

There are a lot of weird things about this makefile but at least this will solve your compile error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If we are using explicitly -I..code/inc to include the header file, then is there any need for generating dependency file main.d here? Could you please share the weird things about the makefile you have encountered. I will modify and update in my project. Thanks

Comment: They are totally different things.  The `-I` option tells the _compiler_ (technically, the preprocessor) where to look for header files when it sees a `#include` statement in your source code.  The generated `.d` file tells _make_ (since you included it in the makefile) which header files the preprocessor included, so that the next time you run `make` it can check if any of those header files have changed, meaning the `.o` file is out of date and needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: Odd things: you declare variables like `DIR_CODE` etc., but then you don't use them everywhere and instead hardcode paths.  Normally I wouldn't expect to have `gcc` etc. written out in a recipe, I would expect to see a make variable like `$(CC)` etc.  Similar with C flags, in the `CFLAGS` variable not written out in the recipe.  It's weird that your rule uses `$(DIR_OBJ)` as an order-only prerequisite, but then lists a different directory `../deps` as a normal prerequisite.  It's almost always wrong to list a directory as a normal prerequisite: this causes lots of unnecessary rebuilds.